# Deploying MVC4 website containing ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I've created an MVC4 website containing an ADO.NET Entity Data Model (linq to entities) but am getting the following error when deploying to a server

```
[ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.
   It may not be installed.]
System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString) +251
```

The DB is SQL Server (System.Data.EntityClient) and this works fine from my laptop. The server is Windows 2008 with .NET 4 installed. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Doh, the Application Pool needed to be "Enable 32bit Application = true"

Comment: Glad it works, but that sounds wrong to me - why would you only be able to run this in 32-bit? SqlClient is provided by Microsoft so should exist as 64-bit already. Is the EF install really 32-bit only?